# try catch cannot read file

Tags: java, file, find, try-catch

Im running this method but for some reason I am not able to find the data record, it keeps going to the catch. Can somebody let me know where I am messing up please. I have the data.txt file in the same directory as the java file.

```
public static Games[] gamesRecord(){
    Games[] game = new Games[50];
    try{
        Scanner dataFile = new Scanner(new File("data.txt"));        
        for(int i = 0; i > 50; i++){
            game[i].title = dataFile.next();
            game[i].releaseDate = dataFile.nextInt();
            game[i].redistributions = dataFile.nextInt();
            game[i].platformRelease = dataFile.next();
        }
    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("File data.txt was not found");
        System.out.println("or could not be opened.");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    return game;
}
```

Comment: Make sure data.txt is actually data.txt, not data.txt.txt. I know this has happened to a lot of people.

Comment: It would help if you printed out the exception stack trace...

Comment: To begin with (although not directly related to the problem at hand) change `i > 50` to `i < 50`

Comment: the name was set up incorrectly, it was data3, changed it and I still got the same problem, unfortunately im not getting a stack trace, just the exception I placed above

Comment: Do `e.printStackTrace();` in your `catch`.

Comment: thanks sotirios, cant find the file, worked after i placed the full path, do you know why it would not be able to find the file even though i have it in the same directory, using netbeans btw.

Comment: When you don't provide an absolute path, the path is resolved relative to where the `java` process was started. It has nothing to do with the file being in the same folder as your class.

Comment: Like @SotiriosDelimanolis comments, add a `e.printStackTrace()` within the catch loop so we can see the exception being printed out. The problem appears to be the wrong File or filename...

Comment: gotcha, thank for the big help

Comment: If you are using Netbeans or Eclipse, you probably need the "data.txt" file in the root Project folder. Let us know if that works, up vote the answer if it addresses the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solve issue by placing full path of the file

Comment: @mikeyaworski I deleted my comment, but I still think this should be more detailed, in order to improve the usability for other users having the same issue.